# 2 similar question about how to find the $a_n$s and $b_n$ of a Fourier series

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

Find the terms $b_n,\ n\geq 1$ so that $$x-\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n \sin nx$$ for all $x\in (0,\pi)$.

A similar one:
Find the term $a_n, \ n \geq 0$ so that $$x-\frac{\pi}{2}=\frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n \cos nx$$ for all $x\in (0,\pi)$.

Could any one give me just a hint because that I think it is rather an algebra problem once you get the trick.

Comment: You have to build periodic functions base on the function $x\rightarrow x-\frac{\pi}2$, given that in the first case the RHS is odd, whereas in the second case the RHS is even, hence you have to build respectively an odd perdiodic function, then an even periodic function. Only then, apply what you know about development in Fourier series or what user164587 summed up below. The trick is to build the right periodic function (extand the domain knowing it's even or odd, then extend the domain by periodicity) And don't forget [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions)

Comment: Just to add to what @Jean-ClaudeArbaut said, note that in the first case, when you extend $x\mapsto x-\pi/2$ to an odd function (and thence implicitly to a $2\pi$-periodic function), there will be jump discontinuities at every multiple of $\pi$. At these points, the series will converge to the wrong value. This is why you get equality only for $x\in (0,\pi)$ instead of $x\in[0,\pi]$. On the other hand, in the second case, when you extend to an even function, the result will be continuous everywhere (and of bounded variation), so you actually get convergence on $[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Real thanks to both of you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much do you know already?

A $\sin$ series of a function defined on the interval $(0,\pi)$ is the Fourier series of an odd function defined on $(-\pi,\pi)$. The $\cos$ series being the Fourier series of an even function.

If we suppose that we have the full Fourier series of a function $$f(x) = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos nx + b_n \sin nx$$
and that certain convergence criteria hold on the series, we can multiply $f(x)$ by one of the trigonometric terms, $\cos kx$ for example, and integrate on the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$.
$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x = \frac12 \int_{-\pi}^\pi a_0\cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi a_n \cos nx \cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{-\pi}^\pi a_n \sin nx \cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x$$
But since $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos nx \cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x = 0 \qquad \forall n \ne k$$and$$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin nx \cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x = 0 \qquad \forall n,k$$
The RHS of the previous equation is just $$a_k\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos^2 kx \, \mathbb{d}x = \pi a_n$$
So we get $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-pi}^\pi f(x)\cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x$$
And when $f(x)$ is an even function on $(-\pi,\pi)$ (as it must be when the series is a cosine series, have all $b_n = 0$, we get $$\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^\pi f(x)\cos kx \, \mathbb{d}x$$

Similar work gets the equivalent result for the $b_n$ in a sine series.